# Why does this code make an led glow red?

Tags: c, arduino

I've written this simple piece of code for testing out my arduino and RGB led.

```
int redled=11;
int blueled=10;
int greenled=9;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(redled, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(blueled, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(greenled, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  digitalWrite(greenled, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(blueled, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(greenled, LOW);
  digitalWrite(blueled, LOW);
  delay(1000);
}
```

Here is a picture:

[image]

(220Ω resistors, in case you are wondering.)

As you can see, I've coded the green and blue to blink, but after I upload it onto my arduino, the red LED actually blinks. Why is this happening? How do I fix it?

Any help would be appreciated!

***UPDATE:***

When I unplug the red wire altogether, the program works as expected, but now, when I plug it back in, it flashes like this:

WHITE
red
WHITE
red

What is the problem now?

Comment: Which LEDs are connected to which pins and how?

Comment: @abligh I will upload a picture of it.

Comment: can you paste the definition of digitalWrite?

Comment: @bare_metal `digitalWrite` is provided by the Arduino SDK.

Comment: is the black supposed to connect to ground/5V?

Comment: @bare_metal according to the picture, black (which should connect to common) is attached to +5V, which presupposes a common anode tricolor LED.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you have not turned the red LED off. Off means it needs a `HIGH` on the pin as you have a common anode configuration, so the LED elements go on when the voltage is `LOW` (not `HIGH`).

You are flashing the blue and green outputs, but the red pin is low all the time. So that means it is on (as the common anode is at +5V). This is because blue+green+red = white (when the blue and green outputs are `LOW`), whereas red alone is obviously red (when the blue and green outputs are `HIGH`).

So add in `setup()`:

```
 digitalWrite(redled, HIGH);
```

Comment: I tried some stuff. Read the update. When I connect the one I think is red to 5v, the led stops flashing.

Comment: See my amended answer - all is explained.

Comment: Thanks for telling me. I didn't know that common anode LEDs have `HIGH` for off and `LOW` for on.

Comment: The common anode is attached to +5V. So for current to flow (and light the LED), the relevant output needs to be at a `LOW` voltage, so current flows from the common anode to the output through the LED. If you had a common cathode LED, that common cathode would be at 0V, so you'd need a `HIGH` output for the current to flow from there through the LED to 0V.